# JWPlayer creating problems in IE8

Tags: drupal-7, jwplayer

JWPlayer is giving me this error in IE8.

```
Error Loading Player: Could not load player configuration
```

It's rolling to Flash so I know it's showing it in Flash but not showing the video. It's playing in all the other browsers.

I can't paste the code here as it's the Drupal module.

Thanks

Comment: Please give us a link to a live page. We can't just guess.

Comment: Please provide a link.